# IndexError using python-ntlm

Tags: python, urllib2, ntlm

I'm trying to use `urllib2` and `python-ntlm` to connect to an NT authenticated server, but I'm getting an error. Here's the code I'm using, from [the python-ntlm site](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/):

```
user = 'DOMAIN\user.name'
password = 'Password123'
url = 'http://corporate.domain.com/page.aspx?id=foobar'

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
# create the NTLM authentication handler
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

# create and install the opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# retrieve the result
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
return response.read()
```

And here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 112, in get_ntlm_data
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 398, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 511, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 430, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 370, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_ntlm-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\ntlm\HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py", line 99, in http_error_401
    return self.http_error_authentication_required('www-authenticate', req, fp, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_ntlm-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\ntlm\HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py", line 35, in http_error_authentication_required
    return self.retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(req, auth_header_field, None, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_ntlm-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\ntlm\HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py", line 72, in retry_using_http_NTLM_auth
    UserName = user_parts[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I ended up giving up and using curl instead.

Comment: am having this same problem, but using suds with uses python_ntlm

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
user = r'DOMAIN\user.name'
```

Comment: just for completeness, `user = 'DOMAIN\\user.name` would work as well. String escaping is what was the problem. And I think it should be @ryan-mcgreal who should mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: The problem was that the authentication was failing, and this is handled poorly in the library.  It would be nice to point that out, for others googling for the symptom / error message.